# Presto - Union & Limit

Tags: sql, union, presto

At the moment, I have a CTE which is building up a list of data and a random row number

What I want to do is output several queries union-ed together based on some of the criteria. The query works fine with a union, but won't work when I add a limit to any of my queries.

Is there a way I can run my query and get my different subsets?

Example:

```
with selection as (
select account, address, type, random(1000)
from details
)

select 
  account,
  address
from details
where type = 'a'
order by random 
limit 50

union all

select 
  account,
  address
from details
where type = 'b'
order by random 
limit 50

union all

select 
  account,
  address
from details
where type = 'c'
order by random 
limit 50
```

Comment: Note that `selection` isn't used.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't need a union here at all:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type ORDER BY random) rn
    FROM details
    WHERE type IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
)

SELECT account, address
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 50;
```

If you really did want to go the union approach, then the following syntax might work, with each limit subquery inside a separate closure:

```sql
SELECT account, address
FROM
(SELECT account, address
 FROM details
 WHERE type = 'a'
 ORDER BY random)
UNION ALL
(SELECT account, address
 FROM details
 WHERE type = 'b'
 ORDER BY random)
UNION ALL
(SELECT account, address
 FROM details
 WHERE type = 'c'
 ORDER BY random)
```